# Filter / Remove EF5 Navigation properties with reflection

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

I have the following code to get all the properties of a generic entity which was passed in. I thought such properties would make great heading for an excel report. But when I use it, I get a bunch of "navigation" properties. I'd like to filter them out cause they are messing up the report. Here is some code...

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(TEntity).Name);

//Get properties / field names
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

//Add props to datatable
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
```

And so the code proceeds to add the other lines to the datatable which I then use to send the data to the excellent NPOI free excel exporting tool.

Is there ideally a BindingFlags property that will allow me to ignore these something like

```
| !BindingFlags.Navigation
```

I also don't necessarly need the other 2 as I get the same details it seems with or without them.

If there is not a BindingFlags property, is there a way I can extend it.

If not, then is there some other standard way of reliably detecting them so I can filter them out.

I heard that some of them contain "Navigation" as a prefix, or are almost always virtual, but while mine seem to be all virtual the "almost" part worries me. This is why I don't want to do something like:

```
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && !p.GetGetMethod().IsFinal).ToArray();
```

However mine do not have "Navigation" prefix that I can see but if they did I am not convinced that this would give me the right way either.

Perhaps I am wrong about the above two or am not looking in the right places.

I've also completed something along the lines of generating a "ViewModel" of sorts which connects to a repo to get the data from the model and populate the ViewModel. Then sending this into my reporting engine. This seems much more flexible as I can use it sort of like a preview if I attach a view to it. Does this sound like the right way to go?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have access to your DbContext? If so, you could query your DbContext metadata (via IObjectContextAdapter.GetMetadataWorkspace) for more informations about your entitytype.

Comment: @user3411327 - I do have access to the context. Would you have any idea how to go about this? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Well as sugested by Francis, you can use the metadata of the DbContext, something like this, to get navigation properties of a given entity type:

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetNavigationProperties<TEntity>(DbContext context)
        where TEntity: class
    {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        var elementType = objContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.ElementType;
        return elementType.NavigationProperties.Select(prop => typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(prop.Name)).ToArray();
    }
```

Then you can filter you properties, excluding the navigation ones, and you code could be something like this:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(TEntity).Name);
var navProperties = GetNavigationProperties<TEntity>(ctx);

var props = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

//Add props to datatable
foreach (var prop in props.Except(navProperties))
    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
```

Comment: I will give this a try over the next weekend or two. Thanks for your help.